# WITH Clause syntax error getting in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, common-table-expression

I am attempting to join multiple tables/views inside `with` clause but it failing. Please help me.

```sql
with a as (
    select
        *
    from
        db.a
),
b as (
    select
        *
    from
        db.b
),
c as (
    select
        * 
    from
        b
    where
        col = 'Hi'
),
d as (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        c P
    WHERE
        col = 'Y'
),
e as (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        b P
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                a
            WHERE
                col= 'Y'
        ) M ON p.col1= M.col1
    WHERE
         P.Date > current_date - 5
)
select
    *
from
    e
```

Getting Error any thing wrong in it:

> Teradata with clause help
> Teradata with clause help
> Teradata with clause help
> Teradata with clause help
> Teradata with clause help

Comment: try to start with only one with and then add one after another, to see where the orioblem lies, second naming the cte with names that are exist in he dat5abase, is a bad choice

Comment: I'm not a Teradata user, but generally speaking `SELECT *` in a CTE is a bad idea - what happens if you use explicit columns?